# Send a spoofed sms on android using sim card

Tags: java, android

I recently made an app which could send messages using the android smsManager api, and was wondering if there is a way to send a sms message through the an android api where the id of the sender is spoofed.

this is the current state of the code I used which sends the message to my cell:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(recipient, scAdress, msg, null, null);
```

I've tried to edit the scAddress, but the message doesnt send (I was seeing if that would work, and wasn't sure what scAdress was)

I am also aware that I could use a site like Twilio or Tropo, but I want to send the message through the sim card, not over the internet.

Comment: I believe that a good answer will be too big to address your question with some acceptable level of detail and correctness. Bottom line is: Your operator will probably block any attempt to spoof the source.

Comment: According to document, `scAddress` is  the service center address or null to use the current default SMSC.

Comment: @Joshua yea, I'm still very unsure about what that means.

Comment: @Ersats SMSC stands for Short Message service center. Its purpose is to store, forward, convert and deliver SMS messages. If you are not building your own SMSC, then you should leave it null and use the one on SIM.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are interested in doing this on your current SIM via other means. Sorry I can't be of more help there. However, this does sound like a fun way to play with Twilio Wireless. You should check out the [documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/wireless).